# Spring - Instantiating beans results in infinite recursion and (ironic) StackOverflow exception. How to fix?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

When I launch my application, for some reason not apparent to me it is waiting until it instantiates the `SchedulerFactoryBean` to instantiate the `jtaTransactionManager` bean. When it does this, Spring goes into an infinite recursion starting from  resulting in a StackOverflow exception.

After tracing hte code, I see no circular dependency - transaction manager is not dependent in any way on the `SchedulerAccessor`

In the stack view image at the bottom, the Proxy$98 class is some enhancement of `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor`

---

**Edit 1: Update**

What is happening is that the `SchedulerFactoryBean` is being initialized in the `preInstantiateSingletons()` method of the bean factory. The transaction manager is not a singleton, so it is not pre-initialized.  When Spring goes through the advisements, it tries to initialize the bean, but the advisement leads it back to the same pathway.

---

**Edit 2: Internals (or infernals)**

The spring class `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration` implements the transactionManager attribute as a LazyProxy.

This is executed well before the initialization code constructs the actual TransactionManager bean. At some point, the class needs to invoke a transaction within the TransactionManager context, which causes the spring container to try to instantiate the bean. Since there is an advice on the bean proxy, the method interceptor in the `SimpleBatchConfiguration` class tries to execute the `getTransaction()` method, which in turn causes the spring container to try to instantiate the bean, which calls the intergceptor, which tries to execute the `getTransaction()` method ....

---

**Edit 3: @EnableBatchProcessing**

I use the word "apparent" a lot here because it's guesswork based on the failure modes during startup.

There is (apparently) no way to configure which transaction manager is being used in the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation. Stripping out the `@EnableBatchProcessing` has eliminated the recursive call, but left me with an apparent circular dependency.

For some unknown reason, even though I have traced and this code is called exactly once, it fails because it thinks the bean named "configurer" is already in creation:

```
@Bean({ "configurer", "defaultBatchConfigurer" })
@Order(1)
public BatchConfigurer configurer() throws IOException, SystemException {
    DefaultBatchConfigurer result = new DefaultBatchConfigurer(securityDataSource(), transactionManager());

    return result;
}
```

---

The code that initiates the recursion is:

```
protected void registerJobsAndTriggers() throws SchedulerException {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = null;
    if (this.transactionManager != null) {
        transactionStatus = this.transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
    }
```

AppInitializer Startup Code:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    try {
        // DB2XADataSource db2DataSource = null;

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(DatabaseConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(ExecutionContextConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(SimpleBatchConfiguration.class);
        rootContext.register(MailConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(JmsConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(SchedulerConfig.class);
        rootContext.refresh();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

}
```

Construction of `jtaTransactionManager` bean in `DatabaseConfig`

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
@Order(1)
public BitronixTransactionManager bitronixTransactionManager() throws IOException, SystemException {
    btmConfig();
    BitronixTransactionManager bitronixTransactionManager = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();
    bitronixTransactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(3600); // TODO: Make this configurable
    return bitronixTransactionManager;
}

@Bean({ "transactionManager", "jtaTransactionManager" })
@Order(1)
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException, SystemException {
    JtaTransactionManager mgr = new JtaTransactionManager();

    mgr.setTransactionManager(bitronixTransactionManager());
    mgr.setUserTransaction(bitronixTransactionManager());
    mgr.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
    mgr.setDefaultTimeout(3600);
    mgr.afterPropertiesSet();

    return mgr;
}
```

Construction of `SchedulerFactoryBean` in `SchedulerConfig`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("transactionManager")
public void setJtaTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager) {
    this.jtaTransactionManager = jtaTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
@Order(3)
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    Properties quartzProperties = new Properties();

    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass",
            delegateClass.get(getDatabaseType()));
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", getTableSchema()
            + ".QRTZ_");
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class",
            org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.class.getName());
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName",
            "MxArchiveScheduler");
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "3");

    SchedulerFactoryBean result = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    result.setDataSource(securityDataSource());


    result.setNonTransactionalDataSource(nonJTAsecurityDataSource());
    result.setTransactionManager(jtaTransactionManager);
    result.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties);

    return result;
}
```

[image: Stack at breakpoint at 2nd level of recursion]

Comment: Pass `PlatformTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager` as parameter to `schedulerFactoryBean` method. You can also annotate the scheduler config class with `@AutoConfigureAfter(DatabaseConfig.class)`

Comment: In order, no change, and @AutoConfigureAfter is not available since this is not a Spring Boot project.  Thanks for the suggestions, they have been helpful.

Comment: Maybe you hit this - "Note that a modular parent context in general should not itself contain @Bean definitions for job, especially if a BatchConfigurer is provided, because cyclic configuration dependencies are otherwise likely to develop."

Comment: Very possibly.  I think I worked past this now. Once the answer is tested out I'll write it up. Afterwards, I'm going to do a very *intense* blog post about the "wonders" of Spring. And the next person who tries to tell me how wonderful the injection model of programming is for clean code may learn some new words.

Comment: @pojo-guy Have you written the blog post yet? it would be helpful. I'm also facing a similar issue after upgrading Spring from 5.1 to 5.2 .

Comment: What I ultimately found was a hidden circular dependency involving the configuration factory bean and the properties API.

When I finally found it, after some careful analysis, instead of using @Autowired I used a lazy init to get the offending bean from the Spring factory at the first actual call to a bean method, thus breaking the cyclical dependency at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several impossibly convoluted to figure out steps to a resolution. I ended up monkeying it until it worked because the exception messages were not information.

In the end, here is the result:

1. refactored packaging so job/step scoped and global scoped beans were in different packages, so context scan could capture the right beans in the right context easily.
2. Cloned and modified `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration` to acquire the beans I wanted for my application
3. Took out the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation. Since I was already initializing less automagically, everything was initializing twice which created confusion
4. Cleaned up the usage of datasources - XA and non-XA
5. Use the `@Primary` annotation to pick out the correct (Biting tongue here - no way to tell the framework which of several datasources to use without implicitly telling it that in case of questions always use "this one"?  Really???)